# Как выровнять текст по центру дива в safari?

Tags: html, safari, css

Здравствуйте. Чтобы выровнять текст по центру дива, в хроме использую такую конструкцию:

```
<div style="display:flex;">
    <span style="margin:auto;">ABCDR</span>
</div>
```

Но сафари не понимает этой конструкции. Подскажите, как правильно выровнять по центру дива в сафари. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для сафари надо display: -webkit-flex.

А вообще, вот такой less рекомендую: http://dpaste.com/1VRN515

Comment: Не помогло, вот полный код: 

    .seradit {
            width: 20%; height: 40px; float: left; margin-left: 10px; border: 1px solid #d6d6d6; display: -webkit-flex;
            
        }
        
        
            .seradit span {
                margin:auto;
            }

Comment: вообще, чтобы выравнять текст по центру, нужно использовать text-align: center.
flex-display всё-таки для раскладки. И один только display: flex не решит, нужно ещё использовать justify-content, align-content и align-items

И, кстати, покажите всю конструкцию на jsfiddle